# Is there a way to stop scikit learn from truncating my (large) output data in a document term matrix?

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn, nlp, sparse-matrix

I am trying to build and store a document term matrix (DTM) from a large corpus of text data. Everything seems to be working except that when I store the to .tsv it takes only saves the first and last 24  entries like this:

(0, 256)  2

(0, 272)  1

(0, 286)  1

: :

(0, 12351)    4

(0, 12353)    5

(0, 12357)    2

I want it to save every entry and not give the : : instead.

I am writing each text entry to a *scipy.sparse.csr.csr_matrix* object like this:

```
briefVector = briefVectorizer.transform(briefInstance)
```

Where briefVectorizer is the features matrix and briefInstance is the raw text data. I am then appending all of these objects to a list like this:

```
briefVectorsList.append(briefVector)
```

Then making that list into a DataFrame column and saving the DataFrame to .tsv.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: can you share the code where you are saving the data frame as tsv? Have you tried saving the file as a pickle file instead incase you need not read the file like an excel?

Comment: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.io.mmwrite.html

Comment: Thanks bindu, here's the code: df_new.to_csv(filePath, sep='\t', index=False)

Comment: I have trouble identifying which variables is a `csr` matrix, which a list, or a DataFrame or a csv file.  Your display with `: :` looks like the `str(M)` of a sparse matrix, which is truncated.  If you have a `csr` in each element of a dataframe column, then this is what I expect - a string representation, not the full matrix.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up working around this problem by saving the Compressed Sparse Matrix as a pickle byte string file, as suggested by bindu madhavi.

All my data is preserved this way.